# Баг с Sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

Всего 5 элементов.

Вот код

```
sqLiteDatabase.delete("data", "name='" + cursor.getString(2)+"'",null);
                            Log.e("asd", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
```

Почему `cursor.getCount()` возвращяет цифру 5, когда должен вернуть цифру 4. хотя в БД если смотреть то там 4 элемента.

Comment: курсор не обновляется после удаления данных из базы. Это не баг, а фича. Он и не должен обновляться

Comment: @metalurgus, спс, из за этой фичи, вся логика моего кода теперь сбилась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как было отмечено @metalurgus, курсор и не должен обновляться, потому что курсор это такой же объект как и все остальные, и единожды в него что-то записав, чтобы получить изменения, нужно выполнить перезапись (`query`). Изучите подробнее работу с `SQLite` в `Android` и сами курсоры. Попробуйте поиграться с методами [rawQuery(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598137/rawqueryquery-selectionargs) и [query(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243199/how-to-perform-an-sqlite-query-within-an-android-application) и всегда передавайте значения в функцию с помощью аргументов, а не хардкодом, поскольку это влияет на безопасность вашей БД и приложения в целом.